# How is electric dipole moment analogous to mechanical moment?

Tags: classical-mechanics, electrostatics, moment

Diplole moment is q*2l. I don't understand the similarity between dipole moment and ordinary mecanical moment.

Answer (score 4):

The *moment* of a quantity is a way of expressing the shape of that quantity. If you have some function $f(\mathbf{x})$ then [the function can be decomposed into a sum of moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)):

$$ \mu_n = \int_\infty^\infty \mathbf{x}^n f(\mathbf{x}) d\mathbf{x} $$

The moments tells us about the shape of the function. The zeroth moment is spherically symmetric, the first moment looks like a dipole, the second like a quadrupole and so on.

Consider your example the two charges, and we'll take the function $f$ to be the charge density. If we put one charge $q$ at $+\ell$ and the other charge $-q$ at $-\ell$ then $f$ has the value $q$ at these two points and is zero everywhere else. Then the first (dipole) moment is:

$$\begin{align}
 \mu_1 &= \int_\infty^\infty \mathbf{x} f(\mathbf{x}) d\mathbf{x} \\
       &= (-q \times -\ell) + (q \times \ell) \\
       &= 2q\ell 
\end{align}$$

Which gives us the usual expression for an electric dipole.

Now suppose the function $f$ is a distribution of forces. Forces are vectors, so $f$ is a vector field and the integral becomes:

$$ \mu_n = \int_\infty^\infty \mathbf{x}^n \times \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}) d\mathbf{x} $$

where $\times$ is the cross product. If we consider the mechanical moment due to a single force $\mathbf{F}$ acting at some point $\mathbf{x}_F$ then $\mathbf{F}$ is zero except at $\mathbf{x}_F$, and for the first moment the integral becomes:

$$ \mu_1 = \mathbf{x}_F\times\mathbf{F} $$

Which is the usual expression (in vector form) for the moment of a force.

So in both cases the term *moment* refers to the same mathematical description of the system.

Answer (score 2):

Two opposite charges +q and -q, connected by a displacement vector $\vec d$, form and electric dipole. An electric dipole is characterized by its dipole moment $\vec p=q\vec d$. In a uniform electrical field $\vec E$, it experiences a mechanical moment (torque) $\vec \tau = \vec p \times \vec E$. So, there is no analogy but there is a relation between both.

[image]

Comment: As John Rennie shows, there is in fact an analogy.